# Rails API on nginx + React frontend returning The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am building an API-only Rails app running on nginx, and have a react frontend on another domain, whenever I attempt to make a request to the api server from react, fetch & axios both return `The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource`. When I use curl or postman to test the API, they both work, and I receive the appropriate headers. I have tried using rack-cors but it doesn't insert the headers when behind a proxy, so I have my virtual host for the API configured like so:

```
# Thin Ruby server
upstream rails_app {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name api.myapp.com;

  ssl_certificate /myapp-secure/myapp.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /myapp-secure/myapp.key;

  access_log /myapp-api/log/access.log;
  error_log  /myapp-api/log/error.log;
  root       /myapp-api/public/;
  index      index.html;

  add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 17280000;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Request-Method' '*';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization' always;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @rails;
  }

  location @rails {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://rails_app;
  }
}
```

And I have a basic login function on the frontend to test a working api endpoint (Should just return an error that no username/password was supplied):

```
  login() {
    axios.post('https://api.myapp.com/v1/login', {
      crossdomain: true
    })
      .then(res => res.json)
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

I have the webpack-dev-server headers configured like so:

```
headers:
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS'
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I'm wasting far too much time trying to overcome this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Chrome is the app that is disallowing CORS. If Chrome doesn't see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` then it will stop the JavaScript. `curl` will always work, because it doesn't enforce header policies. Use `curl -i` to verify your API server is spitting out the right headers. Oh, and all of software development is about wasting too much time trying to figure out something stupid simple.

Comment: @chloe The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': * header is being returned from both the API as well as the frontend webserver, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was two-part, but I was able to work through it and determine what was going on:

1. You cannot use `localhost`, `.dev`, or `.local` domains when making CORS requests. They will **always** be denied regardless of what access policy you have set.
2. Responses from nginx will include the appropriate headers **except** for the case of an xhr request, in which case only the response headers from the proxied service are returned. (Basically don't set any headers in nginx, have your application handle them. In my case rack-cors did the job but only after I removed all headers from nginx)